# How to create a table of 5 GB in HBase for YCSB benchmarking?

Tags: database, hadoop, hbase, ycsb

I want to benchmark an HBase using YCSB. It's my first time using either.

I've gone through some online tutorials, and now I need to create a sample table of size 5 GB. But I don't know how to:

1. Batch-put a bunch of data into a table
2. Control the size to be around 5 GB

Could anyone give me some help on that?

Answer (score 1):

Before, I've used HBase performance evaluation tool to load data into HBase. May be it can help you.

hbase org.apache.hadoop.hbase.PerformanceEvaluation

Various options are available for this tool. For your case you can set the data size to be 5GB.

Answer (score 1):

This is pretty easy, the default (core) workload uses strings that are ~1KB each. So to get 5GB, just use 5,000,000 records.

You can do this by specifying the `recordcount` parameter in the command line, or creating your own workload file with this parameter inside.

Here's how you would do it on the [command line](https://github.com/brianfrankcooper/YCSB/wiki/Running-a-Workload) (using the included workload [`workloada`](https://github.com/brianfrankcooper/YCSB/blob/master/workloads/workloada)):

```
./bin/ycsb load hbase12 -P workloads/workloada -p recordcount=5000000
```

A custom file would look like this:

```
recordcount=5000000
operationcount=1000000
workload=com.yahoo.ycsb.workloads.CoreWorkload

readproportion=0.8
updateproportion=0.2
scanproportion=0
insertproportion=0
```

And then you just run:

```
./bin/ycsb load hbase12 -P myWorkload
```

This will insert all the data into your database.